# JVM Survivor Spaces are not used

Tags: java, garbage-collection, dynatrace

I am currently making a code audit on many java applications for a major energy administration located in France.

I have used many Tools to audit the code (I even wrote a specific parser since I cannot compile the code...). For the performance problem (one of the sides of the Audit), I used `dynaTrace` and it has shown me that the `susrvivor` spaces are totally empty.

In addition the `Eden space` is never garbage collected which provokes large amounts of "stop the world GC" on the tenured space. The `Enden space` is 1GB space, `survivors` are 300MB, and `tenured` is 2,8GB.

Could you help me find an explanation for that strange behavior ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39933015/6162023

> > So will there be ever a scenario to have that objects directly gets copied from eden to Old if objects are smaller in size (not humongous)
> >     ?
>
> If you make the survivor spaces small enough to trigger a full
>   collection each time, the objects will go from Eden to Tenured.

In your case, if the code contains a memory leak (which is the most probable scenario), if the leak is big enough that a Minor GC would fill all of your Survivor space, then objects are moved to the Old Gen (Tenured) space straight away.